Software Update: Package Operation Failed ; How to Fix Broken Install?
I attempted to update via the Software Update. Received error message of 'package operation failed'. So I attempted to run it in the terminal. Below is what I received in response. I have attempted other fixes that I found in this forum (including changing the server from the United States to the main server, running autoclean and autoremove commands, and restarting my computer). I tried the suggestion from this post libpcre2-dev : Depends: libpcre2-posix3 (= 10.39-3+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1) but it is not installed but it did not work.
I am still fairly new to Ubuntu/Linux, so excuse my ignorance. Thank you.
alexander@a-laptop:~$ sudo apt upgrade
[sudo] password for alexander: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.13 : Depends: libpython3.13-stdlib (= 3.13.1-1+noble1) but 3.13.0-1+noble1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
alexander@a-laptop:~$ apt --fix-broken install
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
alexander@a-laptop:~$ sudo apt --fix broken install
E: Command line option --fix is not understood in combination with the other options
alexander@a-laptop:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libpython3.13-minimal python3.13-minimal
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.13-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.13-stdlib
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2,879 kB of archives.
After this operation, 5,458 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y        
(Reading database ... 299492 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.13-stdlib_3.13.1-1+noble1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.13-stdlib:amd64 (3.13.1-1+noble1) over (3.13.0-1+noble1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.13-stdlib_3.13.1-1+noble1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/etc/python3.13/sitecustomize.py', which is also in package libpython3.13-minimal:amd64 3.1
3.0-1+noble1
dpkg-deb: error: paste subprocess was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.13-stdlib_3.13.1-1+noble1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
alexander@a-laptop:~$ sudo apt autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python3.13 : Depends: libpython3.13-stdlib (= 3.13.1-1+noble1) but 3.13.0-1+noble1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).


The packages in your error are 3rd party; where you've provided no sources for us to get details. A quick search here shows the package unavailable for Ubuntu 24.04 or noble, only later releases; so your issue is with a 3rd party source I'm betting & you've not told us what that is.  Also be aware Ubuntu 24.04 LTS uses python3 3.12; so be careful not to change the default as that will break parts of your system (multiple python3 versions can be installed, but do not change the default; esp. on desktop systems).

Thank you for your comment!
Can you tell me how I would know what 3rd party source is giving me trouble? Also, how I could check the default python to make sure I didn't accidentally mess that up?

Edit your question to show the complete output of apt policy libpython3.13-stdlib. That will tell you the 3rd party source you unwisely added. If there are so many that you cannot remember what you have added, then you are well down the path to a broken system.

I was able to solve the issue.
The issue was I had the 'deadsnakes' repository installed. So I disabled it and re-ran the command 'sudo apt --fix-broken install'.
This fixed the issue and I was able to update using the Software Updater.
Thank you all for your help!
